# See this sentence "This is my last night working here"! What grammar structure is it? Reduced Relative Clause?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, gerunds, gerund-phrases

We often reduce relative clauses when **the relative pronoun** is the subject of relative clause.

*The professor **who is teaching mathematics** will leave the university.* Reduced: *The professor **teaching mathematics** will leave the university.* ([source](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107))

"**who is teaching mathematics**" is the relative clause & the relative pronoun "**who**" is subject of relative clause.

But, I am not sure if the sentence "*This is my last night **working here***" ([Jennifer Aniston said in the Friend, at 0:40](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7SAt9h4sd0)) can be interpreted as "*This is my last night **that I work here***" & people removed "**that I**" & changed "**work**" to "**working**" or something like that???.

Also, see other example from the dictionary,

*I will be busy **cleaning the house**.* ([source](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/busy))

Why do they put **a gerund** right after **an adjective** like that?

Note: **[thoughtco says](https://www.thoughtco.com/present-and-past-participles-explained-1211104)**

> The present participle is sometimes used as an adverb to describe the
>   manner in which a verb is performed.
>
> She taught pounding the grammar into their heads!
>
> Angelo works
>   considering all angles.
>
> Notice how the present participle could be preceded with 'by' to give
>   the same meaning:
>
> She taught (by) pounding the grammar into their heads!
>
> Angelo works
>   (by) considering all angles.

Comment: How is “She taught pounding the grammar into their heads!” grammatical without the *(by)*?

Comment: Let us see it slightly changed, "This is my last day (instead of night) working here". What is wrong with this construction.  ...last day/night working here = last day/night that I am working here.

Comment: "busy cleaning the house" is a different construction to "my last night working here". The latter can be the subject of a sentence, the former cannot.

Answer (score 1):

There are two elements in the gerund-participial which are understood through context:

(subject) ***working here*** (temporal location)

The subject of *working* is inferred from *my*.

The temporal location is interpreted through the head noun *night*, which in this case could not possibly be the subject of *working*, and so is understood as the temporal location of the situation expressed by *working here*.

A similar example with a *wh*-relative clause where an adjunct of temporal location has been relativized would be:

> I would like to say a word or two on the subject of this Amendment
> before we pass from it, as this is *the last night **when we shall
> discuss the King's Speech*** (Mr. William Watson, House of Commons, 1937)

Which could be paraphrased as:

> *our last night **discussing the King's Speech***

Though this version would make it seem that the discussion takes up most of the evening, whereas the original simply locates the discussion (however brief) on that evening.

Gerund-participials as post-head modifier in NPs are very similar to relative clauses, but are not analyzed as relative clauses because it is not possible for them to include a relative phrase. (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language p1265)

> **our last night **when** discussing the kings speech*

Other instances requiring a similar interpretation:

> When faced with challenges, Donaldson is fond of telling people that
> on *his first day **working at the State Department in 1973 as
> undersecretary for energy policy***, war broke out in the Middle East.
> (Bush picks polar opposite of Pitt to take over at SEC,   Greg
> Farrell, USA Today 2002)
>
> She'd snuck those shoes out of her mother's closet moments after May
> Jones left for her PTA meeting, and prayed the whole hour and a half
> while her mother was gone that she would hurry back and be so dead
> tired from *her long day **teaching third grade and arguing with the
> parents of Spruce Street Elementary School*** that she'd go straight
> to sleep without making a big fuss over what time Deena turned the
> lights out, and wouldn't come back in the house looking for those
> shoes. (Dreamgirls; Millner, Denene; Harper Collins 2006)
>
> The title, " Ms. Bixby's Last Day, " refers to *her last day
> **teaching at the school*** and the inevitability of *one's last day **living***. (Book review: 'Mrs. Bixby's Last Day' a tale of life, loss for classmates, Virginian-Pilot 2019)
>
> It was like watching a parade of past Julias: a kittenish little
> number she'd worn during *her year **singing a cappella***; a pleated skirt
> and sweater set that had been her daily uniform as a temp. (Julia and Sunny, Sarah Shun-lien Bynum, Ploughshares 2018)
>
> *His years **working in France as a cook*** had left him with culinary
> skills far greater than one would suspect from the three-table
> restaurant he ran with his guest room. (Each Generation Offers Its
> Kindness; Robert M. Press; Christian Science Monitor 1992)

Answer (score 0):

> This is my last night working here.

looks like a combination between

> This is ***my last night here*** AND This is ***the last night (that) I am working here***.

as if ***my*** replaced the omitted ***(that) I am***. The sentence could be re-written as (I am overdoing it, for the sake of analysis):

> This is ***the last night you see me working*** here OR This is ***the last night of my working*** here.

Another [very common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my%20last%20night%20working%2Cmy%20last%20time%20doing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmy%20last%20night%20working%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20last%20time%20doing%3B%2Cc0) phrase of this kind is ***one's last time doing something***:

> To pay for lodging for his horses during the winter, he worked in the Washington woods one summer, ***his last time doing*** so.

The conclusion is that people do use these structures, though it is difficult to find grammatical regulations or explanations for them.

***Busy + ing*** is a totally different story. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) says that in this case  the gerund is

> Part of adjective phrase
>
> - They are all [*busy ***eating*** cakes*].

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/busy) defines busy and shows how it can be used:

> ***busy*** adjective ***(DOING THINGS)***
> If you are busy, you are working hard, or giving your attention to a particular thing:
>
> - Mum was busy in the kitchen.
> - The kids are ***busy with*** their homework.
> - She's ***busy writing*** out the wedding invitations.

So, if you really want to stretch it you could see ***busy cleaning*** as ***busy [with] cleaning*** (in which case the gerund would be used as a noun).
Others have suggested ***in*** or ***while*** instead of ***with***:

> I will be busy [while] cleaning the house.

Here, ***busy cleaning the house*** is seen by certain grammarians as a case of ***Adjective complementation by an -ing participle clause***.

It does seem though that this structure has become much more common especially after [the turn of the third millennium](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Busy%20doing%2Cbusy%20working%2Cbusy%20talking&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBusy%20doing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbusy%20working%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbusy%20talking%3B%2Cc0) which is interesting.

Conclusion: You will find examples with ***busy doing something*** in most dictionaries. It is a correct idiomatic phrase which is particular because it has, as you pointed out, an adjective followed by the -ing form of a verb (without a preposition unlike *bad at joking* or *afraid of diving*).

Comment: *Millennium* derives from 1000 × *annus*, *millenium* [sic] from 1000 × *anus*. Which one did you really mean? :-)

Comment: oops, will edit. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This a reduced relative clause for sure, but your interpretation is incorrect, the reduced relative clause for `This my last night __ working here` is not:

> This is my last night *that I work* here

BUT:

> This is my last night **(that I am) working** here

Why? Because the verb "be" can be omitted in reduced relative clauses, I will cite this rule (look at (d) for a similar example):

> 2. If the relative clause contains the verb 'be' + any of the following then it can be reduced:
>
> (a) ***be* + an adjective phrase**
>
> - The man (**who is**) interested in your car will telephone later.
> - The man interested in your car will telephone later.
>
> Note that other verbs are possible here as well as 'be', such as 'seem', 'look' and 'appear'.
>
> (b) ***be* + a prepositional phrase**
>
> - The books (**which are**) on the table have been read.
> - The books on the table have been read.
>
> (c) ***be* + a past participle [a passive form]**
>
> - A person (**who has been**) tricked once is careful the next time.
> - A person tricked once is careful the next time.
>
> (d) ***be* + a present participle [a continuous form]**
>
> - The family (**who are**) living in the house are very rich.
> - The family living in the house are very rich.
>
> Source: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/relative-clauses-defining-relative-clauses

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103712/discussion-on-answer-by-aesking-see-this-sentence-this-is-my-last-night-working).

Comment: 'I will be busy cleaning the house' is a reduced form of ...?